# Layout and widgets in Android apps

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I am new at Android apps so I have a question which is the bar in the bottom in messenger "Facebook" is it repeated in more than activity or they using fragments?

The bar contains "home, calls, groups, etc." buttons.

Comment: i dont know exactly, because i dont use fb. But the common way to realise "such" a bar is to use toolbar and fragments: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1.It the base class(or you can say super class) which has all the common feature defined we are extending it just extending it the subclass.